# SQL Server Compact 4.0 Select Last DateTime For Each Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a table in SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 where I would like to extract the last record entered each day for every file. So if duplicate entries are made in the same day then only choose the last one for each file.

Column Name (DATA TYPE)

For example:

```
TimeStamp (DATETIME) | FileName (NVARCHAR)
  9/11/2013 4am      | File1.txt
  9/12/2013 11 PM    | File1.txt
  9/12/2013 11:30PM  | File1.txt
  9/12/2013 11:35pm  | File2.txt
  9/12/2013 11:36pm  | File2.txt
  9/13/2013 1am      | File3.txt
```

Would return

```
 9/11/2013 4am     | File1.txt
 9/12/2013 11:30PM | File1.txt
 9/12/2013 11:36pm | File2.txt
 9/13/2013 1am     | File3.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) TimeStamp, FileName
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY DATEPART(dd, TimeStamp), FileName
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad91c/2)** demo